# Add operators to make the equation correct, and give 3 ways to do so

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

I'm trying to solve this puzzle:

> Add operators to make the following equation correct: 4 4 4 4 = 2. Give 3 ways to do so. You are allowed to use brackets if necessary, but no rearranging of numbers or moving the equal sign. You may only use the following math operators: +, -, ×, ÷.

I can think of one or two, but this question wants three ways to do so. Any help in this problem is appreciated.

Comment: This is so hard! I doubt whether there are even 3 ways to do so.

Comment: Can we add operators between 1 and 0?

Comment: Guys, this problem is flawed. I typed it wrongly. It should be 4 4 4 4 = 2. I'm editing it now.

Comment: I knew there was something wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually four ways to do it (the last one is a variation of the third):

> $$4 \div 4 + 4 \div 4 = 2$$

> $$4 - (4 + 4) \div 4 = 2$$

> $$4 \times 4 \div (4 + 4) = 2$$

> $$4 \div (4 + 4) \times 4 = 2$$